# in java How to write code with memory management and CPU uses manage, in Collection java

Tags: java, arraylist, memory-management, collections, cpu-usage

```
public class MillionData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(double i= 0; i<1000000000; i++) {
            str.add(""+i);
            if(i%10 ==0)
                System.out.println(""+i);
        }
        System.out.println("done insertion of "+str.size());

    }

}
```

while running this code CPU Uses reached to 100% and pc is getting stuck how to manage the application where we are inserting lots of data in list or any other Collection where we are storing lots of data but o/p stuck on 1.184349E7 and taking so much time to moving forward how to manage this kind of issue with coding or any other way most prefer to coding

Comment: You usually don't load huge amounts of data into your application: You use a DB and let it do all the heavy calculation (as it's a lot faster and optimized). And if you need to display huge amounts of data, usually you use paging and lazy-load each page to avoid CPU and memory overhead

Comment: Does a `double` have enough precision to even complete that loop? Why is this not an `int` ?

Comment: In case the loop counter itself works, the only thing I can see that you could speed up is removing memory re-allocation overhead by sizing that ArrayList upfront to its required capacity (`new ArrayList<>(1000000000)`). But this is just a toy example and if you want real answers to actual problems, you need to show some real code.

Comment: Re: "Does a `double` have enough precision to even complete that loop?" Okay, up to 1000000000 you should be fine. But seriously, don't loop over floating point.

Comment: Don't use `System.out.println` in tight loops. It's a terrible idea.

Comment: @Thilo `double` can exactly represent all integral values up to `2^53`.

Comment: @Thilo Good question to ask, though. This would be a problem if the loop variable were a `float`.

Comment: @BackSlash how i we can do through pro-grammatically here in this lazy loading in this code?